# Why do they require my passport to travel within the EU for a cruise ship?

Tags: schengen, eu, eu-citizens

I am a Spanish citizen, and next summer I will go on a cruise trip from Spain to France (only stopping in those countries). The organising company seems to be oriented to a USA public so they require the passport for the reservation/registration of the travel as well as the embarkation.

I asked them if I really needed the passport, given that my National ID lets me travel through all EU countries, and they replied that I do need to show my passport when I embark the ship.

Why do they require me to bring the passport?

**UPDATE:** after contacting the company a second time, they answered that the cruise line requires that I have my passport with me although this company is aware of my IDs grants

Comment: Because that's the company's policy. We could speculate about why that's the company's policy but, it would be just that: speculation.

Comment: @DavidRicherby that looks like an answer to me. Why not post it?

Comment: @J.Constantine It's not an answer: it's a statement that the question is unanswerable. It is, literally, a comment on the question, so I posted it as one.

Comment: Traveling within the Schengen zone, you would not need to show your passport or ID card, the company might want to be secure in case you make an extra stop outside the Schengen zone, which could be outside the Schengen zone, but even in most of those cases your ID card should do. I fear the company has someone in the office who does not know the laws involved and is inflexible.

Comment: @DavidRicherby that there is no need for a passport so it must be company policy seems like an answer to me

Comment: @DavidRicherby this company's policy could be unlawful

Comment: Is the company European? Was the person you spoke to European? If not, it's quite likely that they don't even know what a national ID is.

Comment: Would it not more likely be a requirement International Maritime Law (Admiralty Law)?

Comment: I would not be leaving the Mediterranean sea at any time

Comment: Even the Mediterranean see has coasts that would require you to use a passport and not just your ID card, the company might want to be covered in case an emergency evacuation is needed.

Comment: @Dorothy that sounds very unlikely to me.  Do you have any evidence that it might be the case?

Comment: @Willeke: this would be a convincing answer for me. I buy it. Do you not want to make it a formal answer?

Comment: It may have something to do with juridic details around ship flag and international waters.

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could identify the company so we could address its policies specifically.  Company policies of this sort are public record, so there's no reason to hide the company's name.  Searching the internet, I found one thread discussing the policies of Celebrity, which requires a passport, and one traveler checked in saying he was using a "passport" and then entering the national ID number, and not having a problem.  It may just be that you *can* use your ID despite the fact that they appear to be telling you that you cannot.

Comment: Are you certain that the ship itself does not continue on outside Schengen? It's common for cruise companies to market particular itineraries that are just a contiguous subset of the entire journey. And in that case, they want to be prepared in case you do not debark when you should.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because it's easier for them to require passports than to create a special policy for EU citizens. I wouldn't be surprised if non-EU citizens are also asked to prove they're legally allowed to stay within the Schengen area, even though they don't have to check that for intra-EU journeys.

So the answer is: because the company is too lazy to have a reasonable policy.

Comment: @pnuts we have plenty of similar questions, although mentioning the exact company could be helpful. No sources, just like there's no source for why Ryanair checks visas on Schengen flights - they don't tell the public and the rest is speculation.

Answer (score 2):

Look at it from the cruise line's point of view.  There are two policies they could adopt:

1. Accept all the credentials appropriate for every ports they visit and every country their passengers might hail from, which would entail researching the relevant laws, consulting with legal experts, training crew members in the rules, and dealing with complaints from customers who don't understand the final policy.  And Heaven help them if a mechanical or logistical problem forces them to dock in a unplanned port and half the passengers don't have have the proper paperwork to go ashore.
2. Require passports of everyone.

So (2) is the obvious choice.

And you can say they ought to make an exception for such a common case, an EU citizen traveling between EU ports -- and I am sure they have thought about doing so, but have decided against it.

Comment: I have _unassailable_ evidence!  The cruise-line executives, who do nothing but think about these things all day long, have decided not to put such a policy in place. 23 million people a year take a cruise.  If they thought they could bump that to 23.1 million for only a few million dollars invested, they would

Answer (score 1):

While traveling from a Schengen port to a Schengen port, without planned stops, you should not even need to show your passport of ID card.
But when traveling on a sea, unforseen things can happen and your cruise ship might need to call in at a port which is outside the area where your ID is valid.

And there is the possibility of an emergency evacuation, which might land you in a country that does not accept EU ID cards.

But it can also be a case of 'we set the rules, we stick to it.' Without good reasoning.

Comment: @pnuts -- the question is not who these people are, but getting them home.  An EU ID is not going to get you on a plane in Mohammed V International Airport.  Each and every person would have be issued valid travel documents by their own consulate; they couldn't even stay at a hotel without special consideration.  I have no idea how frequently cruise ships are forced into unplanned docking, but apparently... it's often enough.

Comment: @Malvolio "An EU ID is not going to get you on a plane in Mohammed V International Airport" Actually it used to, provided you were on an organized tour